# Perl: Method to convert regexp with greedy quantifiers to non-greedy

Tags: regex, perl

My user gives a regexp with quantifiers that default to being greedy. He can give *any* valid regexp. So the solution will have to deal with anything that the user can throw at me.

How do I convert the regexp so any greedy quantifier will be non-greedy?

Does Perl have a `(?...:regexp)` construct that forces the greedy default for quantifiers into a non-greedy one?

If not: Is there a different way I can force a regexp with greedy quantifiers into a non-greedy one?

E.g., a user may enter:

```
.*
[.*]
[.*]{4,10}
[.*{4,10}]{4,10}
```

While these four examples may look similar, they have completely different meanings.

If you simply add `?` after every `*`/`}` you will change the character sets in the last three examples.

Instead they should be changed to/behave like:

```
.*?
[.*]
[.*]{4,10}?
[.*{4,10}]{4,10}?
```

but where the matched string is the minimal match, and not first-match, that Perl will default to:

```
$a="aab";

$a=~/(a.*?b)$/;
# Matches aab, not ab
print $1;
```

But given the non-greedy regexp, the minimal match can probably be obtained by prepending `.*`:

```
$a="aab";

$a=~/.*(a.*?b)$/;
# Matches ab
print $1;
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask about a specific regex, or quantifier.

Comment: Didn't look hard, did you? Second result for "greed" in perlre answers your question

Comment: @TLP The problem is that the regexp is given by *the* *user*! I cannot control what they enter, so I need a way to do this with *any* regexp. E.g. they may very well enter: '[(?:.*)]' which does not contain any quantifiers, but looks that way - instead it is a character set.

Comment: @ikegami It does *not* answer the question. Re-read the question if you do not understand why. Your reference lists the non-greedy quantifiers. It does not show a general way of converting at greedy regexp to a non-greedy regexp. The naive approach of adding a `?` to every `*` will not work as shown in the question.

Comment: _"construct that forces a greedy regexp into a non-greedy one"_ Does that even exist in _any_ regex flavor? I've never heard of that. Also, as TLP said, this is 99% an XY problem. What exactly do you gain from changing the user's pattern to match something different from what they are looking to match?

Comment: @ikegami "And noone suggested adding ? after every `*`/`}`" So what *did* you suggest by pointing to the reference? Please do not weasel around this and instead quote what you believe would answer the question, and I will explain why it does not answer the question.

Comment: @TLP https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?60400 I am not sure you will understand it from that, so that is why I tried to sum it up.

Comment: Re "*So what did you suggest by pointing to the reference?*",  The docs show that a quantifier is made non-greedy by appending a `?`. It's elementary to conclude that the solution is to add a `?` after each quantifier that doesn't already have a `?` modifier. This is what the reference suggest, and therefore what suggested.

Comment: Using non-greediness for purposes other than optimization is a trap anyway. It doesn't do what you want. You think `a.*?b` will prevent `.*` from matching any `a` or `b`? Think again!

Comment: @ikegami Great. So we agree that you did not come with a solution. Not even close. As you can see from the answers even just appending `?` to every quantifier is a non-trivial problem.  So if we want to convert `a.*b$` into a non-greedy regexp where `.*` does not match any `a` or `b` this will make the solution even harder. I think you provided the best evidence for why your original comment was completely wrong.

Comment: Re "*So we agree that you did not come with a solution.*", I answered the question.  /// Re "*just appending ? to every quantifier is a non-trivial problem.*", Correct. And as such, asking to code to do this is not a valid question. Asking us to write a regex parser is way too broad, and asking for library/tools recommendations is also off-topic. Specifically, SO is not a code writing service. I showed what you had to do, but coding it is up to you. If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask those.

Comment: In your last example there's ambiguity. Why couldn't the "minimal" version be `[.*{4,10}?]{4,10}` or `[.*{4,10}?]{4,10}?`

Comment: @Zaid If the input is 0000000000 the first will match all 10, and the second will only match 4. I am looking for the last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a state machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @regexes = ( ".*", "[.*]", "[.*]{4,10}", "[.*{4,10}]{4,10}" );

for (@regexes) {
    print "give: $_\n";
    my $ungreedy = make_ungreedy($_,0);
    print "got:  $ungreedy\n";
    print "============================================\n"
}


sub make_ungreedy {
    my $regex = shift;

    my $class_state  = 0;
    my $escape_state = 0;
    my $found        = 0;
    my $ungreedy     = "";

    for (split (//, $regex)) {
        if ($found) {
            $ungreedy .= "?" unless (/\?/);
            $found = 0;
        }
        $ungreedy .= $_;

        $escape_state = 0, next if ($escape_state);
        $escape_state = 1, next if (/\\/);
        $class_state  = 1, next if (/\[/);
        if ($class_state) {
            $class_state = 0 if (/\]/);
            next;
        }
        $found = 1 if (/[*}+]/);
    }
    $ungreedy .= '?' if $found;
    return $ungreedy;
}
```

Comment: You need to extend it to correctly handle non-capturing groups `(?:group)`, manually renumbered groups `(?|...)`, closing `}` which are not part of a quantifier - e.g. `hello}`, opening `[` as a part of a character class - e.g. `[a[b]`, but also possessive quantifiers, e.g. `X{2,3}+`, Unicode character classes `\p{IsDigit}`, etc.

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll remark it. But to implementing it would last to long at the moment. Maybe better call another parser out of perl. Then there should be a `/U` flag.

Comment: I rolled back the handling of `?` so there shouldn't be problems with non capturing groups etc.

Answer (score 7):

"Greedyness" is not a property of the whole regular expression. It's a property of a quantifier.

It can be controlled for each quantifier separately. Just add a `?` after a quantifier to make it non-greedy, e.g.

```
[a-z]*?

a{2,3}?

[0-9]??

\s+?
```

And no, there isn't any built-in way to turn the whole regex to some "default-non-greedy" mode. You need to parse the regex, detect all quantifiers and change them accordingly. Maybe there's a regex-parsing library somewhere on CPAN.

---

The closest I've found so far is the [Regexp::Parser module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Parser). I didn't try it, but looks like it could parse the regex, walk the tree, make appropriate changes and then build a modified regex. Please take a look.

Comment: A function that changed the quantifies accordingly would answer the question.

Comment: @Ole Tange, Asking us to write a regex parser is *way* too broad, and asking for library/tools recommendations is also off-topic.